# Xcode ajax call to a local resource

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xcode

We have an xCode app with an `UIWebView` inside. In the webview there is the following JS code:

```
function ajaxCall(file)
{
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax/'+file,cahce:false,async:true,
        success:function(data){$('#holder').html(data)}
    });
}
```

There is a **local** folder called `ajax` filled with HTML files and we're trying to load the asynchronously. When I run the html code from `127.0.0.1` everything is OK, when I run the code as a local HTML file on my laptop it says `'XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/webroot/ajax/file.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.'`. On an iPhone device it is not working too.

I cannot find the error on the iPhone. I've tried to debug it using `error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(textStatus);}` but it says 'error' and nothing more. `errorThrown` is also empty.

What is the correct way to create ajax calls to local files on the iPhone?

FIX: is there a way to create a fake `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` for the HTML files inside `ajax` folder?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Origin+null+is+not+allowed+by+Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: I need a fix / sollution for the xCode - the link is not helping, because most of the topics are for websites.